# Cite Institutional Author in Mendeley

Tags: citations, mendeley

Mendeley automatically formats authors name in the *Last, First* format (e.g., Jane Doe --> *Doe, Jane*). This is a problem when citing institutional authors. For example, if you need to cite the *Substance Abuse and Mental Health Services Administration* Mendeley will automatically format it as "*Aministration, Substance Abuse and Mental Health Services*". Awkward.

Luckily, the solution to this is quick (but not readily obvious). See below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**: Start typing in the institution's name in the author field

**Step 2**: Notice after the text it says "Institution/Organization"

**Step 3**: When you are finished typing in the institution's name, click on the first option in the drop down menu. (*Important: DO NOT press enter!)

[image: Entering Institutional Author in Mendeley]

Comment: I think they have f*#@!d this up with the newer GUI