# Citing Institutional Author or Organization in Mendeley Reference Manager

Tags: citations, mendeley

How do you cite an organization with the new Mendeley Reference Manager?
In order to have the full name of the organization in the Bibliography (e.g. Swiss National Bank) and the abbreviation (e.g. SNB) in the citation?

This question is related to this one:
[Cite Institutional Author in Mendeley](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58584962/18988624)
and this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58584963/18988624

-> However, they provide a solution for the old Mendeley Desktop version, thus I was wondering if there exists a new approach for the new Mendeley Reference Manager?

Answer (score 0):

I sent them a mail a while ago and figured that the best solution is to use JabRef. This works just fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).